# How do I AppendText to a textbox at the time it is entered without duplication in C# Forms?

Tags: c#, forms

I have in a button click event.

```
Button v = (Button)sender;
currentValue = currentValue + Convert.ToString(v.Tag);
txtAnswer.AppendText(currentValue);
```

If v.Tag's value is 2 and I click the button twice, I get 2, 22, 2222, etc. for AppendText.  I can use something like a condition with,

```
txtAnswer.Clear();
```

But that doesn't seem right.

How do I keep it from doubling up?  currentValue acts correctly.  AppendText does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the text directly by assigning to `.Text`.

Comment: If I go off of that textbox and then come back and put in a value, it erases the old one because I have started a new event.

Comment: Then what do you want?

Comment: I want to put 333 + 55, for example.  When I do it it erases the textbox.  I'll just work around it.  I thought I might have made some gross error.